# Copy a Table to another Database in other Connection

Tags: sql-server

I know that two databases are on the same server, but how can I do it if my databases are on 2 different servers?

I need every day update some table getting information from another database.

I want to do a function that i call every day to do this. But i dont know how to do this.

```
 $Connection = ConnectionManager :: get ('adit');


    $resultado = $Connection->execute('SELECT * FROM VLD_ALERGIAS')->fetchAll('assoc');

    /** ALERGIAS **/

    $Connection = ConnectionManager :: get ('default');

    $Connection->execute('DELETE FROM alergias');

    foreach ($resultado as $row)
    {
        $Connection->execute('INSERT INTO alergias (id, nombre) VALUES ('.$row['VLD_ALERGIAS_ID'].', "'.$row['VLD_ALERGIAS_NOM'].'")');
    }
```

I try it but i need do this for each table.

Comment: Please add some more context. There are many ways to do this. With no information it is hard to give you any advice (like I did, which wasn't what you were looking for..)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server and run the query for transferring data from one server to another.

To know the more linked server you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).